# Willl this code snippt collapse in VC6.0?

Tags: c

```
int main(void) {

      int i = 0;
      scanf("%f", &i);

      return 0;
}
```

It is allegedly if I input a float numger, it will collapse.

I have testes it in Gcc4.7, it works.
I hava no VC6.0, so I wanna konw if it will collapse in VC6.0.

If it will, why ? I was told that because the FPU isn't initialized ?

Comment: Nobody uses VC6 and you shouldn't either. It's old and deprecated and has a horrible implementation.

Comment: Passing the wrong pointer type is undefined behavior. It could stop appearing to work any time with any compiler. Don't do it.

Comment: 1) define "collapse" 2) if the compiler does not check for the fact that the format argument should match the format "%", the worst it can happen at runtime is that the size of int is not enough to store a float. I don't know why VC6, even if old and ugly, should "collapse" (the compiled code or the compiler itself?) on that code.

Comment: @ShinTakezou . Plz see my question below the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  int i = 0;
  scanf("%f", &i);
```

You want:

```
  scanf("%d", &i);
```

instead.

`%f` in `scanf` expects an argument of type pointer to `float`. Passing an argument of type pointer to `int` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Yep, I konw this. I just wonder if it will allegedly collapse when I input a float number, why a workaround(also allegedly) of inserting a definition of float variable will fix this?

Comment: @larmbr: reasoning about undefined behavior is pointless. The compiler can do absolutely whatever it wants with that call. You can't rely on any specific behavior. Defining `i` as a float is **not** a workaround. It's a bug fix.

Comment: @Mat Not **redifine** the i to type of float, but insert whatever a float variable definition in whatever place in the code. Quite weird, huh?  I really doubt it and wanna konw why. I was told that it is related to the initialization of FPU ??!!

Comment: @larmbr The person that "told" you this apparently doesn't believe in following the language standard and has no problem embracing the chaos of undefined behavior. You can learn some things from your peers; in this case the some "thing" is what **not** to do.

Comment: @larmbr which question?..they're saying more or less:don't worry about VC6 since your code is not expected to work no matter the compiler(it's UB)."Causing UB" would mean an active intention of a compiler to "behave irrationally"(like flying dragons or similar silliness);actually what happens is very likely that a float is read(interpreting its ASCII representation)and written to the memory pointed by &i; if sizeof(int)>=sizeof(float) everything's fine.Though you can't trust that.Now, "FPU isn't initialized" makes no too much sense to me(if a FPU requires it,why VC6 does not do it?Basic bug!)

Answer (score 2):

This code causes **Undefined Behavior**.
If it works you are (Un)fortunate. It is not guaranteed to work. It might fail or work.

It is your responsibility to make sure format specifier matches the actual type passed in `printf` and `scanf`. Since the actual *type* of `i` is `int` the proper format specifier should be `%d`.

```
  scanf("%d", &i);
```

Comment: s/fortunate/unfortunate/ since you don't know you have a bug.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis but you had a syntax error! `:^)`

Answer (score 1):

I think this refers to old versions of microsoft (and borland, possibly others) compilers that wouldn't have floating point functions in the code unless the compiler detected that you were using floating point (or used some special compiler option to force it). This is a pretty meaningless example, as there is absolutely no way this code would ever work in a reasonable way. If you REALLY want to stuff a floating point value into an integer, using either a type punning pointer cast or a union is the "approved" way.

Not really relevant these days, as floating point support for generic functions (such as *printf and *scanf) is generally provided in the main standard library, and code that is written correctly will not have any problem.

I believe the same problem applies if you were to use %f (or %g) in printf.